# How to format '0000-00-00 00:00:00' using strftime() in python?

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

formatting date as:

```
dob = datetime(0000, 00, 00)
dob = dob.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

but it gives error: `ValueError: year is out of range`

how can i format `datetime(0000,00,00)` using `strftime()` in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's [documentation on the `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html), particularly the `datetime` class states that the `datetime` object can have attribute values in the following range:

> ```
> MINYEAR <= year <= MAXYEAR
> 1 <= month <= 12
> 1 <= day <= number of days in the given month and year
> 0 <= hour < 24
> 0 <= minute < 60
> 0 <= second < 60
> 0 <= microsecond < 1000000
> ```

This module also defines the following constants:

```
datetime.MINYEAR
```

> The smallest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. `MINYEAR` is `1`.

```
datetime.MAXYEAR
```

> The largest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. `MAXYEAR` is `9999`.

which means that you cannot use those (`datetime(0000, 00, 00)`) parameters in the constructor of the `datetime` class, hence the `ValueError` stating that the given year is out of range

Since you can't construct a `datetime` object with the following arguments in the first place, there is no way to call the `strftime` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a year/month/day of value 0.

```
dob = datetime(1989, 1, 1)
dob = dob.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

> '1989-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

It is out of range - there's no [year 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28year%29) in the Common Era, nor a month or day zero in the Gregorian calendar. Beyond that, if time_t is 32-bit you might not be able to process years before 1902 (a property of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

If you really want to produce a string with zeros in it as an example of the format, you could generate one with some functioning date (such as 99-09-09) and replacing the digits with zeros.

In general I prefer sample dates from which you can infer the fields by their values, however, such as 1980-10-30. This doesn't leave room for confusing day and month.

Answer (score 0):

Date, Month and Year cannot be 0. If you wish to give some sort of default value , consider giving it a backdated value like 1st Jan 1970 or any other date that has year in range 1-9999, date in range 1-30(28,29,31 as applicable) and month in range 1-12